# I'm getting a "TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_getitem' and I'm not sure why

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, int, typeerror

I'm trying to throw together a whole lot, but apparently that's not the problem my code has. But I'm not sure what it's talking about in the line of code it's ringing up. It's the very last line that's giving me an error.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

phi = np.zeros(181)

for i in range(0,181):
    phi[i] = i-90.

hF = np.zeros((181,321))
hM = np.zeros((181,321))
Ob = 23.5*3.131592/180
w = np.zeros(321)
e = 0.6

for j in range(0,321):
    w[j] = 2*np.pi*j/320

SF = 3230.3
SM = np.zeros(321)
L = 283

decF = np.zeros(321)

for j in range(0,321):
    decF[j] = Ob*np.sin(w[j])

dF = np.zeros(321)
dM = np.zeros(321)
QF = np.zeros((181,321))

for j in range(0,321):
    dF[j] = (1+e*np.cos(w[j]-L*np.pi/320))/(1-e**2)

for i in range(0,181):
    for j in range(0,321):
        QF = 0
        if np.abs(np.tan(phi[i]*np.pi/180)*np.tan(decF[j])) <=1:
            hF[i][j] = np.acos(-np.tan(phi[i]*np.pi/180)*np.tan(decF[j]))
            QF[i][j] = (SF/np.pi)*dF[j]*(hF[i][j]*np.sin(phi[i]*np.pi/180)*np.sin(decF[j])+np.cos(phi[i]*np.pi/180)*np.cos(decF[i])*sin(hF[i][j]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem line is this:

```
QF = 0
```

And then you try to do:

```
QF[i][j] = ...
```

There is no way you can look up anything on an integer.

Also I noticed that you didn't define a `sin` function but you're trying to use it so I think your last line should read:

```
QF[i][j] = (SF/np.pi)*dF[j]*(hF[i][j]*np.sin(phi[i]*np.pi/180)*np.sin(decF[j])+np.cos(phi[i]*np.pi/180)*np.cos(decF[i])*np.sin(hF[i][j]))
```

Also I noticed you're calling `np.acos` when it should be `np.arccos`.